# unable to get status code of oci-cli command

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

i need to get the response code to use in scripts

like i run a command

```
oci compute instance update --instance-id ocid.of.instance --shape-config '{"OCPU":"2"}' --force
```

i will get this message

```
ServiceError:
{
    "code": "InternalError",
    "message": "Out of host capacity.",
    "opc-request-id": "3FF4337F4ECE43BBB4B8E52524E80247/37CB970D371A9C6BB01DFB23E754FE5B/18DFE9AE75B88A77AB3A1FBEBD3B191B",
    "status": 500
}
```

in this case, i got the error message and a status code 500

but if the commond works, it will output a full json of my instance's parameters, and i can only see a line of response code 200 in debug mode

is there a way to only show the response code?

Answer (score 0):

The ERROR: "Out of host capacity" means The selected shape does not have any available servers in the selected region and Availability Domain (AD). Virtual Machines (VM) are dynamically provisioned. If an AD has reached a minimum threshold, new hypervisors (physical servers) will be automatically provisioned.

There may be some occasions where the additional capacity has not finished provisioning before the existing capacity is exhausted, but when retrying in 15 minutes the customer may find the shape they want is available.

Alternatively, selecting a different shape, AD or region will almost certainly have the capacity needed.

Bare metal instances: Host capacity is ordered on a proactive basis guided by the growth rate of a region. Specialized shapes such as DenseIO do not have as much spare overhead and may be more likely to run out of capacity. Customers may need to try another AD or region.

Comment: thanks, even thought you didn't answer what i asked

Answer (score 0):

Currently OCI CLI does not provide the HTTP response code directly in the response. The response would either contain the service response in case of success or a service error message in case of error.

Can you explain how you are using the HTTP response code in your script? Could you not use the command error code (non-zero on error) to determine the error case?